# Hyperledger Composer vs Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

Is only using Hyperledger Composer (Compared to Hyperledger Fabric) suitable for building a enterprise level application?

Composer is great for building a simple app fast but it seems to be missing a lot of features that fabric has.

Answer (score 3):

Hyperledger Composer is an abstraction layer over Hyperledger Fabric in the same way JQuery or Angular are frameworks over JavaScript. So there is no using Composer without Fabric. Composer generates a RESTful interface for each Channel. For enterprise scale app it is recommended you put an NGNIX load balancer in front of a series of these RESTful endpoints. At Integra Ledger, we put as little business logic and data on the Fabric blockchain and uses standard .NET enterprise SOA techniques.

Answer (score 2):

We can built enterprise level applications using Hyperledger composer there is no doubt in it . But however there are certain things in Hyperledger Fabric gives us more flexibility. For an example, you could not retrive transaction history of a specific asset in composer where as with Fabric you can. Composer uses swagger.io and loopback connecter to generate RestAPI,authentication ,there are some limitations when you use them .To be specific Composer does not support Auth0 authentication.One more thing is this [issue](https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/983).I would say Fabric is more expressive.When you use Fabric you will have all the freedom to mold it (takes a bit of work tough!).

So, using composer or fabric entirely depends up on the complexity of your application.

Answer (score 1):

Hyperledger composer enables to create blockchain application in no time but there are limitations also like you do not have much control on chaincode and transaction mechanism and block structure in this and also there is no authentication provided with the REST APIs so we have to manage these things on our own.